# How can I extract a specific img src url format using regex?

Tags: python, regex, url, extract, src

My string:

```
Russia's National Settlement Depository discusses why it believes the biggest blockchain opportunities have yet to be uncovered.<img alt="" height="1" src="http://feeds.feedburner.com/~r/CoinDesk/~4/rvoQUj-KDaw" width="1" />|One of the co-founder of digital currency startup Stellar announced their resignation today.<img alt="" height="1" src="http://feeds.feedburner.com/~r/CoinDesk/~4/xRzN7syt-v0" width="1" />|The editorial board for Bloomberg News has called for a permissive regulatory environment for blockchain development.<img alt="" height="1" src="http://feeds.feedburner.com/~r/CoinDesk/~4/ooQYB2iDxP8" width="1" />|
```

I wanna get these 3 links into a list:

```
http://feeds.feedburner.com/~r/CoinDesk/~4/rvoQUj-KDaw
http://feeds.feedburner.com/~r/CoinDesk/~4/xRzN7syt-v0
http://feeds.feedburner.com/~r/CoinDesk/~4/ooQYB2iDxP8
```

They obey this pattern:

```
src="http://feeds.feedburner.com/~r/CoinDesk/~4/rvoQUj-KDaw"
```

I know that I should use `re.findall(pattern, string)` to achieve that.

But the big question is: **How can I build a pattern that works here?**

I'm not that good at writing regex patterns.. I always get confused... the one that almost got the job done was this one:

```
pattern = 'http[s]?://(?:[a-zA-Z]|[0-9]|[$-_@.&+]|[!*\(\),]|(?:%[0-9a-fA-F][0-9a-fA-F]))+'
```

But all I got was this list:

```
[u'http://feeds.feedburner.com/', u'http://feeds.feedburner.com/', u'http://feeds.feedburner.com/']
```

It looks like the problem is with the `~r` part and the stuff after that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing the `~` character in your regex:

`http[s]?://(?:[a-zA-Z]|[0-9]|[$-_@.&+~]|[!*\(\),]|(?:%[0-9a-fA-F][0-9a-fA-F]))+`

btw: [this](http://python-regex.com/) is a super way to test regex in Python!

Comment: I've been using regex101, but I liked your website! bookmarked! thx

Answer (score 2):

where is this data coming from ? I'd suggest using an html parser instead of trying to extract with regex. you can pull out the full values from within the tags there if that's coming from html

below i put your string in test.html (for python using beautifulsoup as example)

```
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup(open(r'A:\test.html'))
>>> [x['src'] for x in soup.findAll('img')]
['http://feeds.feedburner.com/~r/CoinDesk/~4/rvoQUj-KDaw', 'http://feeds.feedburner.com/~r/CoinDesk/~4/xRzN7syt-v0', 'http://feeds.feedburner.com/~r/CoinDesk/~4/ooQYB2iDxP8']
```

Comment: While this is good advice, it doesn't attempt to answer the question.

Comment: sorry about that... fixed :)

Comment: Too many things can go wrong with a regex, this would be my preferred choice.

Answer (score 0):

try this script :

```
text1="""Russia's National Settlement Depository discusses why it believes the biggest blockchain opportunities have yet to be uncovered.<img alt="" height="1" src="http://feeds.feedburner.com/~r/CoinDesk/~4/rvoQUj-KDaw" width="1" />|One of the co-founder of digital currency startup Stellar announced their resignation today.<img alt="" height="1" src="http://feeds.feedburner.com/~r/CoinDesk/~4/xRzN7syt-v0" width="1" />|The editorial board for Bloomberg News has called for a permissive regulatory environment for blockchain development.<img alt="" height="1" src="http://feeds.feedburner.com/~r/CoinDesk/~4/ooQYB2iDxP8" width="1" />|"""
import re
print re.findall(r'(https?://\S+)', text1)
```

and the result is

```
['http://feeds.feedburner.com/~r/CoinDesk/~4/rvoQUj-KDaw"',   'http://feeds.feedburner.com/~r/CoinDesk/~4/xRzN7syt-v0"', 'http://feeds.feedburner.com/~r/CoinDesk/~4/ooQYB2iDxP8"']
```

Comment: wow! that's a simple way to fetch all this info. it looks like my head was overcomplicating it!

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
(?:src=)(".*?")
```

and get group \1

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/eI3bF2/2)

Comment: down vote no issues..but explain why.. so that I will correct my self.. ty.